# What is the difference between setting up mod-mono virtual hosts via webapp file versus apache site configuration?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, mono, mod-mono

I'm using mod-mono for deploying an asp.net mvc application on Ubuntu Server 10.04. The following packages were installed: `mono-apache-server4 libapache2-mod-mono apache2`.

There are several blogs that configure mod-mono virtual hosts via the sites-available Apache configuration. For example, I could modify `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` configuration like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    MonoApplications "/:/var/www"
    MonoServerPath /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4

    ... more default configuration
```

But then there are also sites that advise to use an webapp file for mod-mono virtual host configuration. For example, I could modify `/etc/mono-server4/debian.webapp` like this:

```
<apps>
    <web-application>
        <name>default</name>
        <vpath>/</vpath>
        <path>/var/www/</path>
        <vhost>127.0.0.1</vhost>
    </web-application>
</apps>
```

Both approaches however need an apache site `SetHandler mono` configuration setting.

The only difference I noticed is that for sites configuration I have to explicitly define mod-mono-server4 (otherwise the system is trying to start a server2 instance which is not installed). When configured via sites configuration it also seems that there is an additional mono_server process spawned.

I guess I should go with the webapp option, but are there any "big" differences between this two approaches? Is webapp configuration distribution specific or why are there two options anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Webapp config file approach can also be used with stand-alone XSP4, without the need of apache.
For example, you can run:

```
xsp4 --appconfigfile etc/mono-server4/debian.webapp
```

And you'll get XSP4 working with your webapp config file.

Comment: Should we use the ubiquitious mod-mono-server4 rather than xsp4 or fastcgi-mono-server? Thank you.